# Why does NaN * 0.f != 0.0 with Xcode

Tags: c++

I had the problem that uninitialized memory(NaN actually) was used to multiply 0.f then accumulate another value. Finally, I got the NaN. Then I found that

```
NaN * 0.f = NaN.
```

in C++. Is this a necessary result that is not related to the compiler?

Comment: uninitialized memory is not always nan, operations on nan result in nan

Comment: Any floating point operation involving a NaN will produce a NaN. That's not a bug. It's what NaNs are supposed to do.

Comment: Reading the value of an uninitialized variable is undefined behavior. So yes, if that's what you're doing, that's definitely a bug in your code, not in the compiler…apart from that, NaN * 0 is supposed to result in NaN, that's the expected behavior of IEEE 754 floating point, which is almost certainly what floating point numbers are based on on the platform you're targeting…